# grep shows occurrences of pattern on a per line basis

Tags: linux, bash, grep

From the input file:

```
I am Peter
I am Mary
I am Peter Peter Peter
I am Peter Peter
```

I want output to be like this:

```
1 I am Peter
3 I am Peter Peter Peter
2 I am Peter Peter
```

Where 1, 3 and 2 are occurrences of "Peter".

I tried this, but the info is not formatted the way I wanted:

```
grep -o -n Peter inputfile
```

Comment: The string you are searching is a simple string? (or you use regexp operators like `|`, `*` or parenthesis `(` and `)`). What about the number of ocurrences if you search `pepe` and you have something as `pepepe`?  (it does count as one such occurrence or two)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not easily solved with `grep`, I would suggest moving "two tools up" to `awk`:

```
awk '$0 ~ FS { print NF-1, $0 }' FS="Peter" inputfile
```

Output:

```
1 I am Peter
3 I am Peter Peter Peter
2 I am Peter Peter
```

###Edit

To answer a question in the comments:

> What if I want case insensitive? and what if I want multiple pattern
> like "Peter|Mary|Paul", so "I am Peter peter pAul Mary marY John",
> will yield the count of 5?

If you are using GNU awk, you do it by enabling `IGNORECASE` and setting the pattern in `FS` like this:

```
awk '$0 ~ FS { print NF-1, $0 }' IGNORECASE=1 FS="Peter|Mary|Paul" inputfile
```

Output:

```
1 I am Peter
1 I am Mary
3 I am Peter Peter Peter
2 I am Peter Peter
5 I am Peter peter pAul Mary marY John
```

Comment: there are at least 500,000 lines, performance is an issue here with awk, this is via a system call from Perl

Comment: @CindyTurlington: This is pretty efficient, I am not sure you can make it more efficient with grep. Depending on the version of awk you are using, you can probably make it an order of magnitude faster by switching to `nawk` or `mawk`.

Comment: with LC_ALL=A before awk, it seems a lot faster

Comment: @CindyTurlington: Surely LC_ALL=C?

Comment: @CindyTurlington, I suggest you then to write a C program for that.  Regexp is well implemented in C.  But if the search string is static (no regexp operators, like `?` or `*` or `+`) there are algorithms more effective that allow to search without having to check all the characters in the original text.

Comment: Thor, what if I want case insensitive? and what if I want multiple pattern like "Peter|Mary|Paul", so "I am Peter peter pAul Mary marY John", will yield the count of 5?

Comment: @CindyTurlington: With GNU awk that would be straightforward, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need `-o` or `-n`. From `grep --help`:

```
  -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
  ...
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
```

Remove them and your output will be better. I think you’re misinterpreting `-n` -- it just shows the *line number*, not the occurrence count.

It looks like you’re trying to get the count of “Peter” appearances per line. You’d need something beyond a single grep for that. `awk` could be a good choice. Or you could loop over each each line to split into words (say an array) and `grep -c` the array for each line, to print the line’s count.